# How to fix the columns of a gridview and the text of the cells in two rows

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I'm developing a page to display information in a Gridview (ASP.NET), however as this page will be viewed on a smart tv I need the columns to be fixed and the texts of the cells to be restricted.

The RowStyle property with the Wrap as True and the Width property of the columns as a percentage.

Please, I would like a help, because if I change the Wrap to False the size of the GridView gets too large, popping the screen boundary and also could not find how to limit the text size of the cells to two lines.

Thanks in advance for your help and collaboration.

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage2.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="CargaEmProcesso.aspx.cs" Inherits="CargaEmProcesso" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
    <style type="text/css">
        .auto-style3 {
            text-align: center;
            font-size: x-large;
        }
    </style>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
    <link href="Content/FolhaEstilo.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <p class="auto-style3"><strong>Cargas em Processo</strong></p>
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" ForeColor="#333333" AllowPaging="True" PageSize="5" OnLoad="GridView1_Load" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound" CssClass="gridView" >
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="turno" HeaderText="turno" SortExpression="turno" Visible="False" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ci" HeaderText="#" SortExpression="ci" >
            <ItemStyle Width="2%" HorizontalAlign="Right" />
            </asp:BoundField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="data" HeaderText="Data" SortExpression="data" >
            <ItemStyle Width="9%" />
            </asp:BoundField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="saida" HeaderText="Hora Saída" SortExpression="saida" >
            <ItemStyle Width="8%" />
            </asp:BoundField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="cliente" HeaderText="Cliente" SortExpression="cliente" >
            <ItemStyle Width="14%" />
            </asp:BoundField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="email" HeaderText="Inf. E-Mail?" SortExpression="email" >
            <ItemStyle Width="3%" />
            </asp:BoundField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="produto" HeaderText="Produto" SortExpression="produto" >
            <ItemStyle Width="16%" />
            </asp:BoundField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="situacao" HeaderText="Situação" SortExpression="situacao" >
            <ItemStyle Width="9%" />
            </asp:BoundField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="veiculo" HeaderText="Tipo Veiculo" SortExpression="veiculo" >
            <ItemStyle Width="5%" />
            </asp:BoundField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="transportadora" HeaderText="Transportadora" SortExpression="transportadora" >
            <ItemStyle Width="12%" />
            </asp:BoundField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="palletes" HeaderText="Palletes" SortExpression="palletes" >
            <ItemStyle Width="5%" HorizontalAlign="Right" />
            </asp:BoundField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="observacao" HeaderText="Observação" SortExpression="observacao" >
            <ItemStyle Width="11%" />
            </asp:BoundField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="doca" HeaderText="Doca" SortExpression="doca" >
            <ItemStyle Width="6%" />
            </asp:BoundField>
        </Columns>
        <EditRowStyle BackColor="#7C6F57" />
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#1C5E55" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#1C5E55" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="#666666" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <RowStyle BackColor="#E3EAEB" Wrap="True" Height="10px"  />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#C5BBAF" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F8FAFA" />
        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#246B61" />
        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#D4DFE1" />
        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#15524A" />
    </asp:GridView>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:BGConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [ci], [turno], [data], [saida], [cliente], [email], [produto], [situacao], [veiculo], [transportadora], [palletes], [observacao], [doca] FROM [embarque] WHERE ([tipo] = @tipo)">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="2" Name="tipo" Type="Int32" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Please show us a [mcve].

Comment: Sure, the start
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" ForeColor="#333333" AllowPaging="True" PageSize="5" OnLoad="GridView1_Load" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound" CssClass="gridView" >
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
        <Columns>    
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ci" HeaderText="#" SortExpression="ci" >
            <ItemStyle Width="2%" HorizontalAlign="Right" />
            </asp:BoundField>

Comment: the end
        </Columns>
        <RowStyle BackColor="#E3EAEB" Wrap="True" Height="10px"  />
    </asp:GridView>

Comment: Include this as an edit to the original question. The formatting doesn't come out in comments.